# TFS 2010 different views for WIT

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to "teach" the TFS

1. Showing  \ not showing WIT fields for specific users ?
2. Disabling \ Enabling  WIT fields for specific users ?

For Example:

- Administrators \ Contributors - Everything
- Developers - Disable the "Assigned To"
- Outsources - Hide the Area Path

etc...

Comment: Having fields be visible dependent on who is looking at the work item, is not possible. "Disabling" fields by making them read only for specific groups (i.e. Developers and Outsourcers) is totally possible. Do you have sensitive data in the area path that outsourced people should not see?

Comment: Thanks for the responed James, this could be a solution. can you guide me please how to implement this ??

Comment: Definitely. I'll add it as a response so I can add screenshots :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make fields visible dependent upon who is looking at the work item; however, you can make the fields readonly dependent on groups. To do so, see the screen shot below:

(NOTE: I am using the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f). Be aware of the version you are installing)

[image: Export the WITD and open, or open directly from server.]

Export the WITD and open, or open directly from the server.

[image: Add the <code>READONLY</code> rule to a field and then signify a specific group that it is read only for]

Add the `READONLY` rule to a field and then signify a specific group that it is read only for